# Member variable hiding in derived class

Tags: c++

This is the code I have. Base class has member variable `i` and derived class also has same member variable name. Now client creates Base ptr pointing to derived and accesses member variable directly using `i`. I thought it would call derived member variable, instead it calls base class variable. I am not sure why this is?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        int i;
        A(int ii=5):i(ii){}
        virtual void display(){
            cout<<" In A :"<<i<<endl;
        }
};


class B: public A{
    public:
       int i;
       B(int ii=7):i(ii){}
       void display(){
          cout<<" In B :"<<i<<endl;
       }
};


int main(){
   A * aptr = new B();
   cout << aptr->i <<endl; // expected B::i but gave A::i
   aptr->display();
   B bb;
   bb.display();
   return 0;
}
```

Is there a good reason for this. I thought like `vptr` is member variable of object(when new B was called) and this `vptr` calls correctly when  we type `aptr->display`. Why isn't the same thing happening with `i`.

Comment: Member variables can not be "virtual" like member functions.

Comment: Member variables are not virtual methods.
If you want to have `i` behave like a virtual method, wrap it in a getter/setter and make that virtual.

Comment: no my point is , vptr becomes part of object member when class is instantiated eg. class A and class B will have separate vptr and vtable. when i create new B(), vptr of B is attached to it. So when i call ptr->display() vptr of B was picked up and not A hence B::display was properly called. similarly shouldnt be B::i be called when we type ptr->i . since we created instance of B and not A

Comment: variable members are not linked to the vtable, so when you call `aptr->i` you are calling `i` from the base class `A`. On the other hand, when you invoke `aptr->Display()`, `Display` is a virtual function, so `B::Display()` will be called, which will display `i` from the `B` class, because that `i` is in effect hiding the `i` from the base class `A` (remember that the `B` object was created in the `A * aptr = new B();` statement, with its own `i` variable instantiated by the constructor to `7`). To refer to the `i` part of the base `A`, you have to specify it as `A::i`.

Answer (score 3):

Member variables in C++ are not shadowed by inheritance the way virtual functions are.

If `B` inherits from `A`, and they both define a member named `i`, both of those variables exist and are independently part of the object.

Since your pointer has the type `A*`, the expression `aptr->i` will resolve to `A`'s version of `i`.

---

As a side note, `B` can also explicitly access `A`'s version of `i`, as long as it is not `private`.

```
class B: public A{
    public:
       int i;
       B(int ii=7):i(ii){}
       void display(){
          cout<<" In B :"<<i<<endl;
          cout<<" In A :"<<A::i<<endl;
       }
};
```

Comment: sorry , but not impressed with answer. I think i knew this stuff. question is why aptr->i called A::i and while if put in code B* bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>aptr; then call bptr->i will call B::i.

Comment: @rocky_mfe, The question of *why*  polymorphism excludes variables in c++ is one that you will have to ask the language creators. I didn't design c++ so I can only tell you how it works not why.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to ask and luckily was able to write in main func the stuff i needed.
Please check and let me know why A& and A instance behave differntly.

```
int main(){
    A * aptr = new B();
    cout << aptr->i <<endl;
    aptr->display();

    B *bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(aptr);
    bptr->display();
    cout << bptr->i <<"\t" <<bptr->A::i<<endl;

    A & aref = static_cast<A&>(*aptr);
    cout <<endl <<"Called ref : "<<aref.i<<endl;
    aref.display(); // here it calls B::display

    A aa(*aptr);
    cout <<endl <<"Called Inst : "<<aa.i<<endl;
    aa.display(); // here it calls A::display

    delete aptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Question is why aref and aa behave differently? 
My understanding is when instance of B was created using new B(). there were 2 variables in it, "i" and vptr of class B.

When aref is created, it called vptr of B for display, 
but aa calls A::display, 
While for both cases slicing is happening then how does it behave differently.

I am asking question in terms of memory is allocated to any class instance and when ptr of base is pointing to derived class. Hope you understand my confusion.