# Inheritance and pointers of parent class pointing to child class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

So i have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    int x;
    public:
    Parent(){x=10;}
    void f(){cout<<x;}
};

class Child: public Parent
{
  int x;
  public:
  Child(){x=20;}
  void f(){cout<<x;}
};

int main()
{
    Parent *pp;
    Child c;

    pp=&c;

    pp->f();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, i have two classes, Parent class and Child class publicly inherited from Parent class, so i wanted to see what can i do with pointer to a parent class.

I thought that it would be possible to use pointer to the parent class and use it on a child object, as i did in main, however, whenever i run this code, it prints out 10, which is the value i have for parent class variable x, considering that i made pp to point to child object, shouldn't it call the function f() defined in the child class and therefore, it should print the value of 20. What am i missing here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: you have to declare `f` as virtual...

Comment: Read the chapter on polymorphism in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

The method `f` has to be virtual. As a start read [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) maybe helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    int x;
    public:
    Parent(){x=10;}
    virtual void f(){cout<<x;}
 // ^^^^^^^ see this 
};

class Child: public Parent
{
   int x;
   public:
   Child(){x=20;}
   virtual void f(){cout<<x;}
// ^^^^^^^ and this
// or since C++11 with override:
// void f() override {cout<<x;}

};

int main()
{
    Parent *pp;
    Child c;

    pp=&c;

    pp->f();

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16b5e7187762c37e)

Comment: Guess i jumped on pointers too quickly, i should've check out polymorphism in the first place

Comment: One more thing to mention; Pay attention how you name your variables... You have `int x` in both, parent and child. which is not a big issue in your example (since they are private) but could come back someday and bite you -> [member variable hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775804/member-variable-hiding-in-derived-class)...

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems in the code.

First, the function `f()` must be declared `virtual` at least in the `Parent` class (with C++11 and later it is then good practice to append the keyword `override` in the `Child` class). The function being `virtual` is the mechanism that makes it possible to call the `Child` implementation via a `Parent` pointer.

Second, the variable `x` is declared both in the `Parent` and the `Child` class. This means that the `Child` object has two variables called `x` and by default `x` in `Child` functions will refer to the `x` declared in the `Child` class (the copy in the `Parent` class must be `public` or `protected` to be accessible from `Child` and must then, because of the name overlap, be referred to via a `Parent` type pointer or by explicitly specifying the class as in `Parent::x`).